# Trying to get data from a CustomDialog using a Listener not working

Tags: java, android, interface, dialog, listener

I'm trying to get data (Object) from a CustomDialog I created. I want to learn how to use listeners as a learning curve within the CustomDialog to send the Object to the Activity calling the Dialog. I tried following a few tutorials but don't seem to be getting it right. I got an error

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

My CustomDialog is here:

```
public class DetailsDialog extends Dialog implements TextWatcher {
private TextView textCount;
private EditText title, desc;
private Button next;
private DialogListener dialogListener;

public interface DialogListener {
    public void detailsInputted(Memory memory);
}

public DetailsDialog(Context context, DialogListener dialogListener){
    super(context);
    this.dialogListener = dialogListener;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_dialog);

    textCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCount);
    title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
    desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.desc);
    desc.addTextChangedListener(this);
    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Memory memory = new Memory();
            memory.setDescMem(desc.getText().toString());
            memory.setTitleMem(title.getText().toString());
            memory.setFormatedDate(new Date());
            dialogListener.detailsInputted(memory);
            dismiss();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    textCount.setText(String.valueOf(140 - s.length()));
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

}
```

And the Dialog getting called is here:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            DetailsDialog dialog = new DetailsDialog(getApplicationContext(), new DetailsDialog.DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void detailsInputted(Memory memory) {
                    Log.i("MEMORY", memory.getDescMem());
                    Log.i("MEMORY", memory.getTitleMem());
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}
```

It works fine getting the dialog up if I changed the Constructor of the Dialog back to just having the Context so It was working. But I want to get the Object that is set in it. Hope you all can help and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the issue was in the end. Instead of getApplicationContext() in the constructor for the Dialog I needed to put in 'HomeActivity.this'.